# How can I update my QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I want update my QTableWidget but i can't.

TableWidget data come from file( test_data.txt ).

When I press the add button add "ip & protocol" then the data append test_data.txt
but appened data is not appear in my QTableWidget.

this is my code..

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "addip.h"

#include <QFile>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimer()));
    timer->start(1000);

    setWindowTitle( "IP List" );

    QStringList title;
    title << "IP" << "Protocol" << "state";

    ui->ipTable->setColumnCount(3);
    ui->ipTable->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(title);

    refresh_table();
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}


QStringList Dialog::refresh_table()
{
    int field;
    QFile file( "/home/yein/widget/test_data.txt" );

    file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream read(&file);

    while(!read.atEnd())
    {
        QString tmp = read.readLine();
        QStringList tmpList = tmp.split( " " );

        ui->ipTable->insertRow(ui->ipTable->rowCount());
        field = ui->ipTable->rowCount() - 1;

        ui->ipTable->setItem( field, IP, new QTableWidgetItem( tmpList[0] ) );
        ui->ipTable->setItem( field, PROTOCOL, new QTableWidgetItem( tmpList[1] ) );
        ui->ipTable->setItem( field, STATE, new QTableWidgetItem( tmpList[2] ) );
    }
    file.close();

    return table;
}

void Dialog::on_btnAdd_clicked()
{
    QString protocol;
    QString IP;
    int res;
    addIP add(this);
    add.setWindowTitle( "Add IP" );
    res = add.exec();

    if( res == QDialog::Rejected )
        return;

    IP = add.getIP();
    protocol = add.getProtocol();

    qDebug() << "IP :" << " " << IP;
    qDebug() << "Protocol : " << " " << protocol;

    write_on_file( IP,protocol );

}

void Dialog::write_on_file( QString IP, QString protocol )
{
    QFile file( "/home/yein/widget/test_data.txt" );

    file.open( QIODevice::Append );

    data[0] = IP;
    data[1] = protocol;
    data[2] = "0";        // init state 0

    QString _str = QString( "%1 %2 %3\n" )
            .arg( data[0] )
            .arg( data[1] )
            .arg( data[2] );

    qDebug() << _str << " ";

    QByteArray str;
    str.append(_str);

    file.write(str);

    file.close();
}




void Dialog::on_btnClose_clicked()
{
        this->close();
}

void Dialog::onTimer()
{
    updateRStatusBar();
}

void Dialog::updateRStatusBar()
{
    QDateTime local(QDateTime::currentDateTime());

    ui->clock->setText(local.toString());
}
```

Comment: You forget to call `refresh_table` in the end of `write_on_file` method.

Comment: @SaZ I try that but it is occur error.. I add the refresh_table() end of write_on_file() and add ip & protocol. it print table list twice. I don't know why

Comment: That's because refresh_table only adds rows; it doesn't remove rows from the table.  You could make it remove all the rows at the beginning.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html

Comment: thank you for answer!! I solve it!